# How to access property in different view controller?

Tags: ios, storyboard

I have two storyboards and each one has its own respective view controller but I need to change the appearance of the second storyboard based on the button pressed in the first view controller.

In the first view controller I have:

```
// First view controller .h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *LevelOneButton; // tag 0
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *LevelTwoButton; // tag 1

-(IBAction)selectLevel:(UIButton *)sender; // both buttons connected to this method
@property (assign, nonatomic) int levelSelect;

@end
```

then in the first .m file:

```
//FirstViewController.m
-(IBAction)selectLevel:(UIButton *)sender {
    if (sender.tag == 0) {
        _levelSelect = 0;
    }
    if (sender.tag == 1) {
        _levelSelect = 1;
    }
}
```

This code works fine but the problem occurs in the secondViewController that I have. When I try and access the levelSelect property in the SecondViewController I get the errors "Property 'levelSelect' not found on object of type 'FirstViewController'" or "Unexpected identifier levelSelect" or something among those lines. I've tried every single thing I could think of and every question I found on StackOverflow relating to this but none have fixed the problem. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be setting the property on the second view controller as you're pushing or segueing.

So in your first view controller it should look something like this:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "SecondViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *levelOne;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *levelTwo;
@property (assign, nonatomic) int selectedLevel;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.levelOne.tag = 1;
    self.levelTwo.tag = 2;
}

- (IBAction)selectLevel:(UIButton *)sender
{
    if (sender.tag == 1) {
        self.selectedLevel = 1;
    } else {
        self.selectedLevel = 2;
    }

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"pushToSecond" sender:self];

}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    SecondViewController *dest = segue.destinationViewController;
    dest.levelSelect = self.selectedLevel;
}

@end
```

Now, when `viewDidLoad` gets called on the `SecondViewController` that property will be set and you can use it. Like so:

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface SecondViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *levelLabel;

@end

@implementation SecondViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.levelLabel.text = [@(self.levelSelect) stringValue];

}

@end
```

Quick Edit, if you're not using segues you can do the same thing by pushing manually. Would look something like:

```
- (IBAction)selectLevel:(UIButton *)sender
{
    if (sender.tag == 1) {
        self.selectedLevel = 1;
    } else {
        self.selectedLevel = 2;
    }

    SecondViewController *secondVC = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"second"];
    secondVC.levelSelect = self.selectedLevel;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondVC animated:YES];
}
```